# Not able to access appended variable in URL in PHP

Tags: php, url, parameters, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass a variable from one page to another by appending it to the URL like this-

```
<a href='single.php?name=".$m['Title']." ' class='movie-beta__link'>
```

and in the next page(single.php), I am getting the url as-

```
$title= $_GET['name'];
echo $title;
```

But nothing is displayed and my URL looks like this-
    http://localhost/mdb/single.php?name=

Can someone please point out if I am missing something here.

Comment: Can you check your HTML/Page Source to see is the HTML that is being generated by your PHP code ? Looks like `$m['Title']` value might be empty.

Comment: Do you `echo` that link? Otherwise it will not be valid. As @Maximus2012 already mentioned, `$m['Title']` is most likely empty, thus you need to set it.

Comment: @Maximus2012 Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I am able to print the variable   on the page where I am appending the parameter. Moreover, if i am passing a string, like- href='single.php?name=hello , I am able to get it at the other end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<a href='single.php?name=<?php echo $m['Title']; ?>' class='movie-beta__link'>Title</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting your single and double quotes mixed up. With single quotes you have to append variables and with double quotes you can put them inside. But when you're outside of `<?php` tags you can use `<?=` to echo a variable.

`<a href="single.php?name=<?= $m['Title'] ?>" class="movie-beta__line">`

Answer (score 0):

This will work above:

```
<a href='single.php?name=<?php echo $m['Title']; ?>' class='movie-beta__link'>Title</a>
```

if all this is in php echo, use `<a href='single.php?name='".$m['Title']."' class='movie-beta__link'>Title</a>`
And its good to avoid underscores on you class names